# It's possible to have multiple controllers per model (mvc architecture)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, desktop-application

I'm developing a java desktop application and I decide to apply the mvc architecture 
I read [the oracle tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html)

In this tutorial, the writer used one controller for all models.

It is possible to use more than one controller in my application and how *those controllers* can communicate between them ?

Comment: Yes, you can have more than one controller. An easy way to let them work together is by using a dependency injection framework which holds a reference to an implementation in a central place and injects it whenever needed.

Comment: Can you suggest some tutorials using a `dependency injection framework`?

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do, for simplicity and to keep views and controllers cohesive.
Having one controller and view pero function simplifies the modification of those, and simplifies the debugging process.

Normally you will have a main entrance to the application, from wich you will navigate to the diferent views. When creating the other secondary views, as those are dependant of the main one, you can create a reference between them, in order to allow them to comunicate.

Thats what I normally do.